# htaccess: allow access only if rules are fulfilled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've done this htaccess file with a few rewrite rules, but problem is, i'm able to access individual .php files on the server as well a directly access sections like domain.com/admin/change_profile.php

Is this normal? I thought this was not supposed to happen. How do I do this htaccess file so that only if a rule is fulfilled it'll take me to that folder? In short: disallow direct access to domain.com/admin/change_profile.php or domain.com/admin/ or anything else.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(us|uk|eu)/?$ test.php [NC,L] #Country
RewriteRule ^/?(us|uk|eu)/(profile)/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/?$ test.php [NC,L] #Country - Profile
```

Here:

```
http://localhost/us -> Works
http://localhost/us/profile/companyname -> Works
http://localhost/admin -> Works too! But admin is not in the set of rules above. admin is a folder inside htdocs.
```

should not have worked since its not part of (us|uk|eu) rule. Note: Its a folder with php files inside htdocs. How is this happening and how to overcome it.

Comment: What rules do you currently use? Can you post your htaccess file?

Comment: @JonLin I've added a couple of rules I'm working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this normal? I thought this was not supposed to happen.

Yes, this is normal, it's what a webserver does. None of the rules you have match against the URI `/admin/change_profile.php` so none of the rules apply and the webserver does what it's supposed to do: serve the resource that's requested. If you don't want something accessed, you can do one of the following:

- remove the directories from your document root (or move them out of your document root)
- add an htaccess file in the directory you don't want to be accessible with this:

  ```
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  ```
- add additional rules to rewrite directories you don't want accessible in the htaccess file in your document root:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^/?admin test.php [NC,L]
  ```
- route everything to test.php outright:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^ test.php [L]
  ```

Comment: Ok. I thought It'd match only the rules and ignore everything else.